# SignalR - Persistent Connection - Cross Domain - Null Data Received

Tags: signalr

I am using SignalR Persistent Connections with Cross-Domain support and I am able to successfully start a connection, however when I send data from client to server, the server OnReceived method gets invoked, however the data field is always null.

I have traced into SignalR client script and there is valid data at client send time.

Has anyone experienced this ?

Comment: what version of signalr are you using (client, server, everything)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.  The resolution has nothing to do with the environment being cross-domain.   It seems that SignalR assumes that the jQuery $.ajaxSetup defaults are consistent with what SignalR needs, which is a bad assumption....so I had to reset the Ajax defaults prior to using SignalR....

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    processData: true,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    dataType: "text"
});
```

Comment: This is fixed in later versions of the client.